llamaindex RAG AI Agent Claiming Pandas DF Undefined but returning Pandas Queries with accurate keys
I used the base code from this Git project https://github.com/techwithtim/PythonAgentAI/tree/main to setup an initial AI query/response agent. After a few tweaks with llama_index as it changed it's library structure got it fully working. I just wanted to substitute my own data into an alternate dataframe and query my data. Following exactly what he did.
The PandasQueryEngine seems to work as I get suggested Pandas queries that look right (example: dataBlock[dataBlock['Year'] == 2023]['IMPRESSIONS']), but when it goes to get the data an Observation gets generated saying "Observation: Error: name 'dataBlock' is not defined". DataBlock is my df name. Clearly it is defined as the PandasQueryEngine reads it and has accurate header names. I have also exported the data to check for bad cells and all looks good. This seems to be an issue within llama_index, and I have tried to track it down but haven't been able to. I have also rebuilt the venv and updated the libraries.
Verbose error:

Pandas Instructions:

dataBlock[dataBlock['Year'] == 2023]['R_IMPRESSIONS']

Observation: Error: name 'dataBlock' is not defined
Thought: It seems that there was an error in executing the dataBlock tool. Let me try again.
Action: dataBlock
Action Input: {'input': '{confidential} R_IMPRESSIONS 2023'}

Pandas Instructions:
dataBlock[dataBlock['Year'] == 2023]['R_IMPRESSIONS']

Observation: Error: name 'dataBlock' is not defined
Thought: I apologize for the error. It seems that the dataBlock tool is not available at the moment. I will need to find an alternative way to retrieve the information.
Answer: I'm sorry, but I am currently unable to retrieve the total number of R_IMPRESSIONS that Revlon ran for each HMI_SUBCHANNEL in 2023.

**The Code:**
`
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as db
from llama_index.experimental.query_engine import PandasQueryEngine
from prompts import new_prompt, instruction_str, context
from note_engine import note_engine
from llama_index.core.tools import QueryEngineTool, ToolMetadata
from llama_index.core.agent import ReActAgent
from llama_index.llms.openai import OpenAI

#Retrieve datablock from DB Server
dataBlockSQL = """SELECT * FROM [database].[schema].[table]"""
conn = db.connect({**connection string**})
dataBlock = pd.read_sql_query(dataBlockSQL,conn)
conn.close()

dataBlock_query_engine = PandasQueryEngine(
    df=dataBlock, verbose=True, instruction_str=instruction_str
)

dataBlock_query_engine.update_prompts({"pandas_prompt": new_prompt})

tools = [
    note_engine,
    QueryEngineTool(
        query_engine=dataBlock_query_engine,
        metadata=ToolMetadata(
            name="dataBlock",
            description="This source gives detailed media information for clients",
        ),
    ),
]

llm = OpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo")
agent = ReActAgent.from_tools(tools, llm=llm, verbose=True, context=context)

while (prompt := input("Enter a prompt (q to quit): ")) != "q":
    result = agent.query(prompt)
    print(result)
 `


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
